# PHP function to validate IPv4 and IPv6 using regex

Tags: php, regex, string, validation

I'm needing to create a function for IPv4 and v6 that I cause use local ip's as well.

What I know is a valid IPv4 ranges from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255
What I know of IPv6 is limited however as despite it being around for a while I haven't really looked much into it til today. But I want to future proof the function I am making a little bit while keeping it a bit retro for the time being. I'm not sure what the valid ranges are for IPv6.

Anyway In general what I am thinking is a function to the extent of

```
function validateIP($ip, $vSix = NULL)
{
    if($vSix !== NULL)
    {
      if(preg_match([regex-to-validate-ipv6], $ip))
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

    if(preg_match([regex-to-validate-ipv4], $ip))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
}
```

my thing is I suck with regex so I have no idea how to write one that will validate v4 or 6. Also a sanity check on the above function concept would be nice as well.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Check PHP's [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var) function. It has a [number of validators](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php), including IPv4 and IPv6.

```
$isValid = filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4);
// $isValid can be evaluated as boolean, as it's FALSE if validation fails.
```

Comment: Awesome idea, dunno why I failed to remember that on, but good call +1

Comment: `$isValid` is __not__ `boolean`. From the docs: Returns the filtered data, or FALSE if the filter fails.

Comment: @schnittstabil - Younger-me would have said that was pedantic, but in reality this is a fair point. I've updated the example to state that it can be cast to boolean.

Comment: @schnittstabil You're correct but he said it can be _evaluated_ as a boolean, which is not incorrect. I.e. even if filter_var returns the filtered data and you use that data in a conditional and it will still be evaluated to true.

Comment: @Dillan Please note that Morgon have written "I've updated the example"…

Answer (score 24):

**Edit**

Please see Natxet's comment on this answer, and Morgon's answer for a better solution.

**Original Answer**

You can just use [inet_pton](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php). It returns false if the IP is not a valid IPv6 or IPv4:

```
function validateIP($ip){
    return inet_pton($ip) !== false;
}
```

Comment: Man I gotta do some catch up on php.net reading some of these newer functions I didn't even realize. This is very simple and sexy. I think I'm gonna go with this after reading about it just now. Kudos!

Comment: Watch out! This function will throw a warning, and please do not eliminate that using @ before function name. You should avoid using this function for checking a correct IP. As @marc-pro-campos points, the option `return  filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP));` seems the best for you

Answer (score 19):

try

```php
//validates IPv4 and IPv6
$isValid = filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);

//validates IPv4
$isValid = filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP,FILTER_FLAG_IPV4);

//validates IPv6
$isValid = filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP,FILTER_FLAG_IPV6);

//validates IPv4 and IPv6, excluding reserved and private ranges
$isValid = filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Morgon and Mark Pro Campos answers:

```
function is_valid_ip($ip='', $ip_type=''){

    $isValid=false;

    if($ip_type=='ipv4'){

        //validates IPV4
        $isValid = filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP,FILTER_FLAG_IPV4);
    }
    elseif($ip_type=='ipv6'){

        //validates IPV6
        $isValid = filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP,FILTER_FLAG_IPV6);
    }
    else{

        //validates IPV4 and IPV6
        $isValid = filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
    }

    if($isValid == $ip){

        $isValid=true;
    }

    return $isValid;
}
```

**Resources**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 3):

Try:

IPv4

```
/^((2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9])?\d|25[0-5])(\.(?1)){3}\z/
```

IPv6

```
/^(((?=(?>.*?(::))(?!.+\3)))\3?|([\dA-F]{1,4}(\3|:(?!$)|$)|\2))(?4){5}((?4){2}|((2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9])?\d|25[0-5])(\.(?7)){3})\z/i
```

From:
http://home.deds.nl/~aeron/regex/

Comment: what does the \z on the end do?

Comment: Its EOL  (\z equal $)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check into filter_var instead. It has a filter for IP addresses (IPv4 and IPv6): http://us.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score 1):

```
function verify_ip ($ip)
{
    //ipv4
    if(preg_match('#^(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}$#', trim($ip))){
        return true;
    }
    //ipv6
    if(preg_match('#^(((?=(?>.*?(::))(?!.+\3)))\3?|([\dA-F]{1,4}(\3|:(?!$)|$)|\2))(?4){5}((?4){2}|((2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9])?\d|25[0-5])(\.(?7)){3})$#i', trim($ip))){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i know this question is for php - not explicitly laravel.

But for the sake of completeness i will post the solution for php laravel.
To check for valid ipv4 or ipv6 addresses use the following code as value in your validation rules array:

```
// form fieldname to be checked => 'rules ip-separated'
'field1' => 'required|ipv4', // checks for an ipv4 address + field is required
'field2' => 'nullable|ipv4', // checks for an ipv6 address + an empty string is valid as well
```