# php ip validation filter_var with IPv4-translated Address like ::ffff:0:a.b.c.d

Tags: php, filter-var

```
$ip = "::ffff:0:10.0.0.3";
if (!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === false) {
  echo("$ip is a valid IP address");
} else {
  echo("$ip is not a valid IP address");
}
```

this return invalid although it is a valid ip

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try [inet_pton](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php) as answered here: [PHP function to validate IPv4 and IPv6 using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608001/php-function-to-validate-ipv4-and-ipv6-using-regex)

```
function validateIP($ip){
    return inet_pton($ip) !== false;
}
```

That answer also suggests a whole load of methods.
If none of them work then either that is not a valid IP or PHP as a bug that you should report.