# PHP how to check if IP RANGE provided is IPv4 or IPv6

Tags: php

So I have the following two IP ranges

```
2a02:c78::/29
2.120.0.0/13
```

What php function can i use to tell the difference between a ipv4 range and a ipv6 range

Need something like this

```
function ip_range_type($range_ip)
{
//if ip range provided is ipv4 then

//if ip range provided is ipv6 then
}
```

Comment: Regex is what you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function to validate IPv4 and IPv6 using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608001/php-function-to-validate-ipv4-and-ipv6-using-regex)

Comment: `strpos($ip, ':') !== false` should do pretty well…

Comment: According to the duplicate post I like `filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4);`

Comment: @the4kman you did not read my question i am validating if the range is ipv4 or ipv6 RANGE being the key word not the address.

Comment: @deceze if you post it as a answer i can mark it as correct for a solution. Everyone else is failing to read my question but at least you proved you can read and understand it without marking it as a duplicate to a irrelevant question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158961/discussion-on-question-by-c0nw0nk-php-how-to-check-if-ip-range-provided-is-ipv4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit for this solution goes to user @deceze

```
function ip_range_type($range_ip)
{
    if (strpos($range_ip, ':') !== false) {
        //if ip range provided is ipv6 then
        echo "range provided is ipv6";
    } else {
        //if ip range provided is ipv4 then
        echo "range provided is ipv4";
    }
}
$range_ip = "2a02:c78::/29";
ip_range_type($range_ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses has a lot of Ranges like All [IPv4 Ranges](https://ipfind.io/subnet/ipv4) with network addresses & CIDR same you can check for [IPv6 Ranges](https://ipfind.io/subnet/ipv6) too. Answer of your question is already explained here [check IPv4 or IPv6 Range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62602487/13343449) with an efficient way.